# Custoom pandas wide to long

Tags: python, pandas

I have this type of wide dataset which I want to convert to long format. The column `choice` shows the order of the chosen alternative. So, if it is `choice2` it means the second option was chosen and that column should have 1 for the second option and 0 for the others. The columns `college, hsg2 coml5` should repeat.

Data:

```
respondent  choice  college hsg2    coml5   type1   type2   type3   type4   type5   type6   fuel1   fuel2   fuel3   fuel4   fuel5   fuel6
1   choice1 0   0   0   van regcar  van stwagon van truck   cng cng electric    electric    gasoline    gasoline
2   choice2 1   1   1   regcar  van regcar  stwagon regcar  truck   methanol    methanol    cng cng gasoline    gasoline
```

This is what I am trying to achieve. I could not find any ways to convert the `choice` column properly. Any help is appreciated. I looked at the most of the **wide to long and vice versa** questions, but could not solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) first, then get number from `choice` column and compare by counter per groups for final column:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['type','fuel'], 
                     i=['respondent','choice','college','hsg2','coml5'],
                     j='tmp').reset_index().drop('tmp', 1)

df['choice'] = df['choice'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

df['order'] = df.groupby(['respondent','choice','college','hsg2','coml5']).cumcount().add(1)

df['new'] = df['choice'].eq(df['order']).astype(int)
print (df)
    respondent  choice  college  hsg2  coml5     type      fuel  order  new
0            1       1        0     0      0      van       cng      1    1
1            1       1        0     0      0   regcar       cng      2    0
2            1       1        0     0      0      van  electric      3    0
3            1       1        0     0      0  stwagon  electric      4    0
4            1       1        0     0      0      van  gasoline      5    0
5            1       1        0     0      0    truck  gasoline      6    0
6            2       2        1     1      1   regcar  methanol      1    0
7            2       2        1     1      1      van  methanol      2    1
8            2       2        1     1      1   regcar       cng      3    0
9            2       2        1     1      1  stwagon       cng      4    0
10           2       2        1     1      1   regcar  gasoline      5    0
11           2       2        1     1      1    truck  gasoline      6    0
```

If `order` is generated from `type` and `fuel` columns names:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['type','fuel'], 
                     i=['respondent','choice','college','hsg2','coml5'],
                     j='order').reset_index()

df['choice'] = df['choice'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df['new'] = df['choice'].eq(df['order']).astype(int)
print (df)
    respondent  choice  college  hsg2  coml5  order     type      fuel  new
0            1       1        0     0      0      1      van       cng    1
1            1       1        0     0      0      2   regcar       cng    0
2            1       1        0     0      0      3      van  electric    0
3            1       1        0     0      0      4  stwagon  electric    0
4            1       1        0     0      0      5      van  gasoline    0
5            1       1        0     0      0      6    truck  gasoline    0
6            2       2        1     1      1      1   regcar  methanol    0
7            2       2        1     1      1      2      van  methanol    1
8            2       2        1     1      1      3   regcar       cng    0
9            2       2        1     1      1      4  stwagon       cng    0
10           2       2        1     1      1      5   regcar  gasoline    0
11           2       2        1     1      1      6    truck  gasoline    0
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you for your help. Could you please add some comments, especially 
wide_to_long part? I would love to understand how to approach such problems

Comment: @EmilMirzayev - it is parameters - in another words - `i` are columns which need only repeated, `stubnames` are columns with numbers here, so splitted by text and number to `tmp` column (this column is removed).

Comment: @EmilMirzayev - Btw, numbert with `type` and `fuel` should be compared by `chioce` ?

Comment: Apologies, I did not understand the question @jezrael

Comment: never mind, I think second solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is  [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); `pivot_longer` transforms the data to long form:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
     index=slice("respondent", "coml5"),
     names_to=(".value", "num"),
     names_pattern=r"(.+)(.)",
     sort_by_appearance=True)
.assign(choice=lambda df: df.choice.str[-1].eq(df.num).astype(int))
.drop(columns="num")
)

    respondent  choice  college  hsg2  coml5     type      fuel
0            1       1        0     0      0      van       cng
1            1       0        0     0      0   regcar       cng
2            1       0        0     0      0      van  electric
3            1       0        0     0      0  stwagon  electric
4            1       0        0     0      0      van  gasoline
5            1       0        0     0      0    truck  gasoline
6            2       0        1     1      1   regcar  methanol
7            2       1        1     1      1      van  methanol
8            2       0        1     1      1   regcar       cng
9            2       0        1     1      1  stwagon       cng
10           2       0        1     1      1   regcar  gasoline
11           2       0        1     1      1    truck  gasoline
```

The `.value` determines which part of the column name remains as a header. In your data the pattern is `type` followed by a number or `fuel` followed by a number. `.value` pairs with type/fuel and stays as a header, the remaining part(the number) goes into the `num` column. This pattern is what is captured in `names_pattern` as a regular expression of groups.

Comment: this is actually a neat approach! never heard of pyjanitor. any good tutorials you would advise? Unfortuntely only 1 answer could be tagged

Comment: @EmilMirzayev, have a look here for various examples :[pivot_longer](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/examples/notebooks/Pivoting%20Data%20from%20Wide%20to%20Long.ipynb)